# CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT?

Tags: 14.04, cmake

I'm trying to build a github project using cmake and I've been having a lot of trouble. 
I'm creating a build directory and calling cmake like so:

```
cd github_project_directory
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/usr/bin
CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.
```

I think there is a problem with how cmake is installed but I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling but...I think it might have created even more trouble.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Happy to provide more information as required.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the "project name" / a link to the git files.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error for anything cmake, including `cmake --version`, and the "reinstall `cmake` and `cmake-data`, then restart your shell" answers didn't work, so I tried manually setting `CMAKE_ROOT` to the path from `dpkg -L cmake-data` that contains the `Modules` directory.

```
export CMAKE_ROOT=/usr/share/cmake-3.5
```

That got `cmake --version` working, which revealed that I was somehow dealing with a `cmake` that reported itself as cmake 2.x, but a `cmake-data` package which created a `cmake-3.5` folder for its resources.

It turned out that one of my PPAs was offering cmake 3.5 at the same package names that 14.04 uses for cmake 2.8 and, because of a dependency conflict, the `cmake-data` package had upgraded to 3.5, but the `cmake` package was getting held back at 2.8.

The following lines got things working for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake cmake-data
sudo apt-get install cmake3 cmake3-data
```

Answer (score 7):

I had to re-install my cmake to correct this same error.

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake cmake-data
sudo -E add-apt-repository -y ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Then be sure to re-source your rc.

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Running `. ~/.bashrc` solves the problem for me!

Answer (score 3):

Runing `. ~/.bashrc` also solved the problem for me. My total procedure was -

```
sudo apt remove cmake // as it was a old version and i needed new one
pip install cmake --upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I only needed to do a "autoremove and . ~/.bashrc".
No need to uninstall and reinstall

Answer (score 2):

You could use the version from pip

`pip install cmake`

```
➜ ~ cmake --version
cmake version 3.18.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this issue after you install a new/updated/different `cmake` version, please try running `hash -r`.

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615451/cmake-missing-modules-directory