# Install cmake 3.17 failed,CMake has most likely not been installed correctly

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, compiling, cmake

Ubuntu 18.04  past cmake version 3.10.2

After I  have install cmake with `sudo make ,sudo make install`,and `cmake --version`

```
(base) lzw@resplendent-star:~/3d_lib/cmake-3.17.1$ cmake --version
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/usr/local/share/cmake-3.10
cmake version 3.10.2
```

Comment: [Does this help?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014670).Also if you are compiling the project from an external repository, please include its link.

Comment: hi, I am download cmake 3.17 file from cmake.org

Comment: @骆忠伟 I find it easier to install cmake from pip `pip install cmake`, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

can confirm getting same error
`ubuntu 18.04`
updated cmake to `cmake-3.17.2` from https://cmake.org/download/

```
cd $CMAKE_DOWNLOAD_PATH
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

results in

```
def@etho:~/xenium/xenium/build$ CC=gcc-8 CXX=g++-8 cmake ..

CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!

CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.

Modules directory not found in
/usr/local/share/cmake-3.5

CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache().
 
Aborting.
```

answer on here worked well - I used the last comment from DM LOWE.  don't forget to resource your rc

[CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014670/cmake-error-could-not-find-cmake-root)